# How can I search an array in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I want to be able to effectively search an array for the contents of a string.
Example:

```
dim arr() as string={"ravi","Kumar","Ravi","Ramesh"}
```

I pass the value is "ra" and I want it to return the index of 2 and 3.

How can I do this in VB.NET?

Comment: Shouldn't you get 0,2,3?  You're clearly doing a case-insensitive filter.

Comment: Passing in "ra" would get you 0, 2 and 3.

Comment: Make your question clearer case sensitive or what??

Comment: Which version of VB.NET?  Most of the answers seem to be 3.0+.

Comment: He meant 3.0+ for .NET version.
:P

Answer (score 17):

It's not exactly clear how you want to search the array. Here are some alternatives:

Find all items containing the exact string "Ra" (returns items 2 and 3):

```
Dim result As String() = Array.FindAll(arr, Function(s) s.Contains("Ra"))
```

Find all items starting with the exact string "Ra" (returns items 2 and 3):

```
Dim result As String() = Array.FindAll(arr, Function(s) s.StartsWith("Ra"))
```

Find all items containing any case version of "ra" (returns items 0, 2 and 3):

```
Dim result As String() = Array.FindAll(arr, Function(s) s.ToLower().Contains("ra"))
```

Find all items starting with any case version of "ra" (retuns items 0, 2 and 3):

```
Dim result As String() = Array.FindAll(arr, Function(s) s.ToLower().StartsWith("ra"))
```

-

If you are not using VB 9+ then you don't have anonymous functions, so you have to create a named function.

Example:

```
Function ContainsRa(s As String) As Boolean
   Return s.Contains("Ra")
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim result As String() = Array.FindAll(arr, ContainsRa)
```

Having a function that only can compare to a specific string isn't always very useful, so to be able to specify a string to compare to you would have to put it in a class to have somewhere to store the string:

```
Public Class ArrayComparer

   Private _compareTo As String

   Public Sub New(compareTo As String)
      _compareTo = compareTo
   End Sub

   Function Contains(s As String) As Boolean
      Return s.Contains(_compareTo)
   End Function

   Function StartsWith(s As String) As Boolean
      Return s.StartsWith(_compareTo)
   End Function

End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim result As String() = Array.FindAll(arr, New ArrayComparer("Ra").Contains)
```

Comment: I think he was looking for the index

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim inputString As String = "ra"
Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length).Where(Function(x) arr(x).ToLower().Contains(inputString.ToLower()))
```

Comment: Corrected. I confused the parameter `x` with `inputString`

Answer (score 2):

If you want an efficient search that is often repeated, first sort the array (`Array.Sort`) and then use [`Array.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In case you were looking for an older version of .NET then use:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim arr() As String = {"ravi", "Kumar", "Ravi", "Ramesh"}
        Dim result As New List(Of Integer)
        For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length
            If arr(i).Contains("ra") Then result.Add(i)
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Don't forget ToLower... the algorithm as written would not return 2 and 3, only 0.

Comment: That's his choice As well as Contains or ForEach;
He didn't really say if he wants his check to ignore case, or if he wants his query to be "StartsWith" or "Contains" function, that's his choice.
Look on previous post.

Answer (score 2):

check this..

```
        string[] strArray = { "ABC", "BCD", "CDE", "DEF", "EFG", "FGH", "GHI" };
        Array.IndexOf(strArray, "C"); // not found, returns -1
        Array.IndexOf(strArray, "CDE"); // found, returns index
```

Answer (score 1):

compare properties in the array if one matches the input then set something to the value of the loops current position, which is also the index of the current looked up item.

simple eg.

```
dim x,y,z as integer
dim aNames, aIndexes as array
dim sFind as string
for x = 1 to length(aNames)

    if aNames(x) = sFind then y = x
```

y is then the index of the item in the array, then loop could be used to store these in an array also so instead of the above you would have:

```
z = 1
for x = 1 to length(aNames)
    if aNames(x) = sFind then 
        aIndexes(z) = x 
        z = z + 1
    endif
```

Answer (score 0):

**VB**

```
Dim arr() As String = {"ravi", "Kumar", "Ravi", "Ramesh"}
Dim result = arr.Where(Function(a) a.Contains("ra")).Select(Function(s) Array.IndexOf(arr, s)).ToArray()
```

**C#**

```
string[] arr = { "ravi", "Kumar", "Ravi", "Ramesh" };
var result = arr.Where(a => a.Contains("Ra")).Select(a => Array.IndexOf(arr, a)).ToArray();
```

-----Detailed------

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim arr() As String = {"ravi", "Kumar", "Ravi", "Ramesh"}
        Dim searchStr = "ra"
        'Not case sensitive - checks if item starts with searchStr
        Dim result1 = arr.Where(Function(a) a.ToLower.StartsWith(searchStr)).Select(Function(s) Array.IndexOf(arr, s)).ToArray
        'Case sensitive - checks if item starts with searchStr
        Dim result2 = arr.Where(Function(a) a.StartsWith(searchStr)).Select(Function(s) Array.IndexOf(arr, s)).ToArray
        'Not case sensitive - checks if item contains searchStr
        Dim result3 = arr.Where(Function(a) a.ToLower.Contains(searchStr)).Select(Function(s) Array.IndexOf(arr, s)).ToArray
        Stop
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: That scales badly, as it will loop through the array one extra time for each match found.

Comment: The problem is that he wants the index, he doesn't want the values.

Comment: There is no property Index in an array child.
It's actually a good idea, all the items in an array should have a property Array to access the array and Index to have the index of this item in the array...

Comment: Array.FindAll(arr, Function(s) s.ToLower().StartsWith("ra"))

I have used your code in VB.NET 2005 but i am getting error in Function keyword. It is not accepting, please help

Comment: I posted another code which is applicaple in .NET 2.0, the previous code was for 3.0+ (maybe only 3.5 donno, but not for 3.0).

Comment: And if your concern is performance rather than code readability then use the code in the following reply, simple For loop this will iterate just ince as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Never use .ToLower and .ToUpper.

I just had problems in Turkey where there are 4 "i" letters. When using ToUpper I got the wrong "Ì" one and it fails.

Use invariant string comparisons:
Const LNK as String = "LINK"
Dim myString = "Link"

Bad:
If myString.ToUpper = LNK Then...

Good and works in the entire world:
If String.Equals(myString, LNK , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then...

Answer (score -1):

This would do the trick, returning the values at indeces 0, 2 and 3.

```
Array.FindAll(arr, Function(s) s.ToLower().StartsWith("ra"))
```

Comment: This won't return the indices but the actual elements, which is not the OP specifies.

Comment: Array.FindAll(arr, Function(s) s.ToLower().StartsWith("ra"))

I have used your code in VB.NET 2005 but i am getting error in Function keyword. It is not accepting, please help

Comment: Dim result2 = arr.Where(Function(a) a.StartsWith(searchStr)).Select(Function(s) Array.IndexOf(arr, s)).ToArray

Comment: This code would only work in VB 9.0+ (i.e. Visual Studio 2008). You should always specify which version you are using in your question.