# Trouble translating a function from PHP to VB.NET

Tags: php, vb.net

I am more of a PHP Coder then VB.net Programmer so I made this and was wondering if someone could be so kind as to help me converting this function.

```
<?php
function grabshade($r,$g,$b){
$colors = array(array(0, 0, 0), array(255, 255, 255));
$differencearray = array();
$colors2 = array(
'black' => array(0, 0, 0),
'white' => array(255, 255, 255));

foreach ($colors as $col2) {
$delta_r = $r - $col2[0];
$delta_g = $g - $col2[1];
$delta_b = $b - $col2[2];
$distance = $delta_r * $delta_r + $delta_g * $delta_g + $delta_b * $delta_b;
array_push($differencearray, $distance);
}
$smallest = min($differencearray);
$key = array_search($smallest, $differencearray);
return $key = array_search($colors[$key], $colors2);
}
?>
```

The PHP Script will take a r,g,b value and return if its closer to white or black.

This should be working but it isn't returning anything.

```
Public Function findshade(ByVal r, ByVal g, ByVal b) As Integer
Dim colors As New ArrayList()
colors.Add("0:0:0")
colors.Add("255:255:255")
Dim differencearray As New ArrayList()

Dim colors2 As New ArrayList()
colors2.Add("0:0:0")
colors2.Add("255:255:255")
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To colors.Count - 1 Step i + 1
    Dim colorsparts As String() = colors(i).Split(":")
    Dim delta_r As Integer = r - colorsparts(0)
    Dim delta_g As Integer = g - colorsparts(1)
    Dim delta_b As Integer = b - colorsparts(2)
    Dim distance As Integer = delta_r * delta_r + delta_g * delta_g + delta_b * delta_b
    differencearray.Add(distance)
Next
differencearray.Sort()
Dim minValue As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(differencearray(0))

Dim result As New ArrayList()
For ii As Integer = 0 To differencearray.Count
    If differencearray(ii).Contains(minValue) Then result.Add(i)
Next
Dim key As Integer = result(0)
Dim result2 As New ArrayList()
For ii As Integer = 0 To colors2.Count
    If colors2(ii).Contains(key) Then result2.Add(i)
Next

Return result2(0)
End Function
```

Comment: What progress have you made so far?  What stumbling blocks are you encountering?  There's nothing specific to PHP here that would not translate *immediately* into *any* other language... okay, maybe `array_search` might require some hoop jumping.

Comment: I don't know much about VB.net, like I don't know how to form arrays for that task (like able to edit the keys name), or like you said array_search.

Comment: @Joseph, thanks for the update.  I've updated the title of this post to make it something more useful and hopefully attract useful attention.  I don't know any VB myself, so I won't be *too* much help.  `array_search` is going to be the only problem here, I think.  Thankfully it can be implemented as a simple iteration over an array, ending when it finds the value.  This will, of course, actually mean using real arrays instead of splitting on a string...

Comment: Ive reedited what ive done, ill look threw places for array_search.

Comment: Ive finished what I assume should be the translation but it isn't returning a value so im back to the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a seperate approach, The php code I made was meant for alot more then 2 colors, it was meant for (originally) 20. It was used to determine the closest color you input out of the colors of the array, but since Now I am only doing Black and White Closest I simplified everything.

```
 Public Function findshade(ByVal r, ByVal g, ByVal b) As Integer
        Dim delta_r As Integer = r - 255
        Dim delta_g As Integer = g - 255
        Dim delta_b As Integer = b - 255
        Dim distance As Integer = delta_r * delta_r + delta_g * delta_g + delta_b * delta_b


        Return distance
    End Function
    Public Function findshade2(ByVal r, ByVal g, ByVal b) As Integer
        Dim delta_r As Integer = r - 0
        Dim delta_g As Integer = g - 0
        Dim delta_b As Integer = b - 0
        Dim distance As Integer = delta_r * delta_r + delta_g * delta_g + delta_b * delta_b


        Return distance
    End Function
```

Function findshade will find how close your entry is to white, and findshade2 will find how close your entry is to black.

To determine if the pixel should be black or white you get both entrys and find the smallest value which isn't hard from there.

```
TextBox1.Text = findshade(255, 255, 255).ToString
TextBox2.Text = findshade2(255, 255, 255).ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a quick function in VB.NET. Hope it helps you.

```
''' <summary>
''' Find the array index of the value if found in the String array. Else returns -1
''' </summary>
''' <param name="StringArray"></param>
''' <param name="Value"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Function ArraySearch(ByVal StringArray As String(), ByVal Value As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To StringArray.Length
        If StringArray(i) = Value Then
            Return i
        End If
    Next
    Return -1
End Function
```

**PHP array_search can be implemented in VB.NET**

[How can I search an array in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697270/how-can-i-search-an-array-in-vb-net)

Comment: Thats not really the full question, but ive already looked into that post and im adding it in now. Ill see where it taks me.

Answer (score 0):

For a more generic approach you can use [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/) to compile PHP code as CLR, then use [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx) to translate it into VB.Net code.

I'm thinking in case you have loads of code to translate. The output code will not be perfect for human eyes, but will be executable.