# visual basic array searching

Tags: .net, arrays

I'm trying to search an array for previous entries from a user inputted text box that match new incoming entries.  Is there any way to do this in Visual Basic?  I'm converting my code from C# and Visual Basic keeps giving me an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."   With this statement, the code skips the if block to check for matching text because arrayName(i) or 0 in this case is currently NOTHING.  If i take out this if block and it reaches the name check, then it causes an error because  there is nothing in arrayName(i) to convert to upper string.

So here's my code..My question again was is there an easier way to search previous entries from an array to newly input entries.

Edit: details

This is the array declaration `Dim arrayName() = New String(2) {}` and when it gets to If arrayName(i).ToString.ToUpper = txtInput.Text.ToUpper Then it says "Object variable or With block variable not set." "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code".  The "x" in the code is the fixed length of the array, which is 2 in this case.

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
            While x >= i
                If arrayName(i) IsNot Nothing Then
                    If arrayName(i).ToString.ToUpper = txtInput.Text.ToUpper Then
                        match = False
                        lblName.Text = "Enter a unique name"
                    End If
                End If
                    i += 1
            End While
```

Comment: You probably have the same question as this thread :) Check it out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697270/how-can-i-search-an-array-in-vb-net

Comment: Which line specifically is causing the exception? The exception provides you with that information. What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code? What is the declaration of `arrayName`?

Comment: @Tim oh wait :) Is your question about the error that pops up or 'easier way to search previous entries from an array to newly input entries'? or both?

Comment: @chris_techno25 well it's both because this method doesn't work, and I would like to know if there's a good method to use for this function

Comment: @Tim Then this thread should probably answer both of your questions :) It uses the built-in method of searching an array, so you shouldn't have any error if used correctly and plus the code is short, which answers your 'fast method' issue :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697270/how-can-i-search-an-array-in-vb-net

Comment: @chris_techno25 yeah but I don't know the contents of my array so I can't search by substrings

Comment: @KenWhite ` Dim arrayName() = New String(2) {}`  and when it gets to `If arrayName(i).ToString.ToUpper = txtInput.Text.ToUpper Then` it says "Object variable or With block variable not set." "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code"

Comment: @KenWhite oh hey Sir, I just noticed you posted a comment. Can we be friends now? :) I'm sorry I just got a little mad because I honestly never saw your comment and answered the question by myself. And you said you didn't mean that, that puts away all the negative aside :)

Comment: @Tim So you want a function that tells you if what you just entered was already entered previously right? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @chris_techno25: No worries. We're fine.

Comment: @KenWhite So we're good now. You are still gonna help me with programming right? :)

Comment: @Tim: So you have a two-dimensional string array of two elements, each of which is an array? Then your problem is clear: You need to reference it as `arrayName(0)(i)` or `arrayName(1)(i)`. (And that array declaration is relevant to your question, so you should have included it there. If you want help, provide sufficient details in your question so we can try and provide it.)

Comment: @chris_techno25: Yes, as long as you avoid calling me rude names. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite It's a 1-d array. the 2 is the upperindex. So I have 0, 1 and 2 elements, or 3 total spots in the array saved.

Comment: @Tim: Please [edit] your question and provide details there, instead of burying them in comments.

Comment: @KenWhite Understood Sir. I won't I promise :) I actually never call anyone rude names. I was just mad and the mad me took over. But that doesn't correct the wrong, so I get it :)

Comment: @Tim Can you edit your question? We might be able to edit your code if you give us exactly what you want... :)

Comment: @chris_techno25 I just want a way to search through the elements of my array, comparing them to newly input strings.  (These strings that are being entered are what the array consists of, even though the first time it runs through, there are no elements in the array)

Comment: @Tim Alrighty... So if the user inputs a name already in the array? Is that allowed?

Comment: @chris_techno25 No, I want to check and not allow any duplicate names into the array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to use built-in search functions...Try this...

Declare this under Global Scope...So put it just under the form class...

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0
Dim arrayname(10) As String
```

Add a button control... and add this code...

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If counter < 10 Then
        Dim input As String = InputBox("Please input name.")
        If input = "" Then
            MsgBox("Nothing entered!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For x = 0 To 10
            If UCase(input) = UCase(arrayname(x)) Then
                MsgBox("Duplicate name!")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next x
        arrayname(counter) = input
        counter += 1
    Else
        MsgBox("Array full!")
    End If
End Sub
```

That's it. Edit to suit your exact needs. Tell me if it works :)

Comment: It has an issue!  I can enter the same string many times and it doesn't catch them as a match for some reason.  I stepped through the code and it executes the compare statement but goes to the Else every time to add to the array

Comment: It's still doing it :/

Comment: I added some variables to see what the code is doing while it's stepping through and it appears that the array isn't storing the variable when it reaches the end of the code, any ideas why?

Comment: @chris_techno25, you should include the upper limit of 10 for the string array in your For loop. VB is different from C# in that when you Dimension an array, the array is zero based and goes inclusively to the number of the subscript. So in this case, there are 11 elements in the string array.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman Thank you Sir. Yeah I was thinking it was the same array rules as C# :)

Comment: @Tim Yeah it shouldn't store anything more after you finish filling up every array value. That's what I did. If you want to reset back to zero then you can add a chunk of code to reset the counter variable. I tried listing the array values into a listbox and the code above does work :) Can you try it again?

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet hasn't defined `x`.

You can search your array efficiently with a little bit of LINQ:

```
Dim listFound As IEnumarable(String) = From item In arrayName _
                                       Where item.ToString.ToUpper _
                                       = txtInput.Text.ToUpper _
                                       Select item
If listFound.Count > 0 Then
    lblName.Text = "Enter a unique name"
End If
```

Or you can manually search the array, but I think this is more efficient that the method you are using:

```
Dim Match As Boolean = False

For i As Integer = 0 To arrayName.Count - 1
    If Not IsNothing(arrayName(i)) Then
        If arrayName(i).ToString.ToUpper = txtInput.Text.ToUpper Then
            Match = True
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
If Match Then
    lblName.Text = "Enter a unique name"
End If
```

Two last items of note: `arrayName(i).ToString.ToUpper` is equivalent to `UCase(arrayName(i))`. You may want to perform some speed tests to see which is actually faster.

Also, `Dim myArray As String(3)` is not the same thing in VB as `Dim myArray() = New String(3) {}`. The first example results in a 1 dimensional array. The last example results in a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: x is just the fixed length of my array

Comment: No, it isn't defined at all. You explicitly show `i`'s definition and instantiation. If `x` is defined, why not include it in the code sample?

Comment: Because there's a lot more code that isn't relevant to the question.  It's just an array with a fixed length, but isn't initialized with any data

Comment: I tried the bottom code and for some reason when I step through the debugger and it reaches the if not statement, even if i enter the same string twice, it doesn't enter the if block, it just skips over it and then goes to the next

Comment: Remove the curly braces from your declaration of arrayName and your issue should resolve itself.